How to make metaphors make sense in a writing instead of making it out of topic
I was writing something that I thought of couple days ago.
it was about the people's mindset that they created throughout their life, and I wanted to describe it in a metaphorical way.
now to make sense to this, I obviously need to add metaphors to it.
But my problem was, even though I knew I needed to use metaphors in it, I couldnt fit it in a way that would make sense. I could explain it, but then, the piece I wrote about that metaphor, the part I explained about it, feels off from the previous part.
say i wrote :
A jar will hold more doesnt mean it is strong. Some people fake it when theyre actually 
very fragile. One can just slightly tap on its body, and boom… a crack appears, which wouldnt have happened
in the glass because its strong. 

The jar might have been beautiful, but its fragile, its weak to its surrounding,
and unless someone is guarding it with their life,
they will have a high risk of breaking it. 
The jar here represents fragility, and security. Its creator could’ve 
been fragile their whole life, living by walking on a strand of a rope, 
never knowing when they’ll lose their balance and fall. The jar here 
represents a potential higher than that glass from before. Ya its fragile, 
but it doesnt mean that its useless. If one is careful enough, it can hold 
enough to fill multiple glasses. It can hold enough to fulfil someone’s 
huge thirst that was not satisfied with a small glass. 

it's not a poem, I just took a piece of a thought writing I recently wrote.
in this, a metaphor that I thought of:
a glass jar made like a prince rupert's tear

it might not make sense right now, and i'm not trying to, because this piece is raw. I need to refine it.
I tried using keywords that represented the metaphor: Fragility, resilience, hidden flaw, and I tried making sense out of it. but when I try putting the actual metaphor i thought of, it doesn't make sense.
im neither a avid writer nor a writer that writes daily.. so all I do is read through stuffs and when I feel like I can, I try doing it.
but this time, I got stuck on a piece.
it's not just this one, there's more, I already wrote more than just the one I showed, and there are more ideas on my mind, waiting to overflow.
But I really can't help but feel that I can't write at the moment because the parts I want to include on the writing cant make sense at all.
Is there any formula that people use to write these metaphors, or do they just slap it in and hope it works?
Any ideas and advice is appreciated, no matter how small. Im suffering with writer's block right now, and no solution that is currently on the internet is helping me.

I think I understand what you're trying for, but as glass jars do NOT walk on tightropes you've created a bizarre 'mixed metaphor' tangent in the middle of your analogy. 1 metaphor per customer.

that is one of the problem im facing.. i tend to create metaphors on the moment, and dont realize how mixed, or how confusing it is, unless someone explains it to me.. its just what i am right now.
and about the tightrope, its not meant to describe the jar itself. it describes what the condition the person is in... its just... metaphorical

No offense, because we have all had those 'a ha..' moments, but this is just editing. It is a second skill that must be learned after pouring words onto a page, we then must go back and cut what is unnecessary or distracting.

im kinda struggling to decide what to put , where to put and  how to put it. im struggling to decide what i should remove, so, you know, it wont be boring and somewhat repetitive. im trying to put something that might not make sense, yet make sense at the same time.. i know its confusing, but i really cant explain too much. i havent practiced this skill enough
